# Oracle Create formula for dynamic SQL to prevent divide by zero

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql, divide-by-zero, regexp-substr

I have a table with formula column that have formula to fetch to dynamic SQL LIKE `n5/n14+n3`

My problem is when formula have divide, I should try convert the formula to prevent error `divide by zero`.

My current idea is convert formula to `CASE` when it have divine, for e.g `n5/n14+n3` to `CASE WHEN n14 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE n5/n14+n3 END`,

but I can convert only in case formula have only 1 divide, and cannot convert in case formula have > 1 divide ( e.g `n5/n4+n3/n2`, or formula have divide by an expression (e.g `n5/(n4+n3)`.

Could anyone have solution for that?

```
WITH tmp AS 
(
    SELECT 'n5/n14+n3' AS formula FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'n5/n14+n3/n1-n2' AS formula FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'n8/(n17*n6)-n5/n4+n3/n1-n2' AS formula FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'n5/(n14+n3*n2)-n1' AS formula FROM dual 
)
SELECT
    formula,
     CASE
         WHEN formula NOT LIKE '%/%' OR REPLACE(formula, ' ', '') LIKE '%/(%' OR (LENGTH(formula) - LENGTH(REPLACE(formula, '/', ''))) > 1 THEN  formula
         ELSE 'CASE WHEN ' || SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(formula, ' ', ''), '/(n\d+)'), 2) || ' = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ' || formula || ' END'
     END AS formula1,
     'CASE WHEN ' || SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(formula, ' ', ''), '/(n\d+)'), 2) || ' = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ' || formula || ' END' AS formula2
 FROM tmp t;
```

Current result is not expected output (only line 1 resolve divide by zero error):

```
formula                     formula1                                    formula2
n5/n14+n3                   CASE WHEN n14 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE n5/n14+n3 END CASE WHEN n14 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE n5/n14+n3 END                
n5/n14+n3/n1-n2             n5/n14+n3/n1-n2                             CASE WHEN n14 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE n5/n14+n3/n1-n2 END          
n8/(n17*n6)-n5/n4+n3/n1-n2  n8/(n17*n6)-n5/n4+n3/n1-n2                  CASE WHEN n4 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE n8/(n17*n6)-n5/n4+n3/n1-n2 END
n5/(n14+n3*n2)-n1           n5/(n14+n3*n2)-n1                           CASE WHEN  = 0 THEN 0 ELSE n5/(n14+n3*n2)-n1 END
```

Comment: Your idea (to show the result 0 in case of division by 0) is terrible. How will you know that there was an error, and the result 0 shouldn't actually be used for anything further? Best to leave that as `null` (or, even better, let the result have an additional column for short error messages, if needed - in this case it would show "divide by zero").

Comment: @mathguy do you have some idea how to do it? Currently formulas is in a table, and after fetching them I wil run dynamic sql like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE temp SET ' || l_cursor.col_name || ' = ' || l_cursor.formula`, and I don't know which row would it rasise error (or maybe luckily, no zero, no error..) and how to handle it when error was thrown.

Comment: @mathguy Ah I understand that, If my dynamic SQL `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` raise Error, I should log that error and continue to next formula in table. But unfortunately, that should not happen in my case, I should omit error and apply formula to other rows in dynamic SQL, and in my case return NULL instead of Divide by zero, as Mr @Linoff suggest is sufficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NULLIF()` to prevent an error.  The result will be `NULL` instead:

```
(
    SELECT 'n5/nullif(n14, 0)+n3' AS formula FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'n5/nullif(n14, 0)+n3/nullif(n1, 0)-n2' AS formula FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'n8/nullif(n17*n6, 0)-n5/nullif(n4, 0)+n3/nullif(n1, 0)-n2' AS formula FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'n5/nullif((n14+n3*n2, 0)-n1' AS formula FROM dual 
)
```

Comment: Thanh you for your idea, But formula is data in a table, and I cannot manually edit them like that. I will try using some `REGEXP_REPLACE` when SELECT to change those formulas using `NULLIF`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mr @Linoff's suggestion, I do use `` to fetch and convert formula using `NULLIF` like this

```
WITH tmp AS 
(
    SELECT 'n5/n14+n3' AS formula FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'n5/n14+n3/n1-n2' AS formula FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'n8/(n17*n6)-n5/n4+n3/n1-n2' AS formula FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'n5/(n14+n3*n2)-n1' AS formula FROM dual 
)
SELECT formula,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(formula, ' ', ''), '\/(n\d+)|\/(\([^\)]*\))', '/NULLIF(\1\2,0)') AS formula1
FROM tmp;
```

Result:

```
formula                     formula1                                    
n5/n14+n3                   n5/NULLIF(n14,0)+n3                                     
n5/n14+n3/n1-n2             n5/NULLIF(n14,0)+n3/NULLIF(n1,0)-n2                     
n8/(n17*n6)-n5/n4+n3/n1-n2  n8/NULLIF((n17*n6),0)-n5/NULLIF(n4,0)+n3/NULLIF(n1,0)-n2
n5/(n14+n3*n2)-n1           n5/NULLIF((n14+n3*n2),0)-n1
```

Comment: This regex will not handle multiple brackets like `a1/(a2+a3) + (a4+a4)/a5`. Things get even worse when there are nested brackets which cannot be handled with simple `\([^\(]+\)`. I think this task is better to address to PL/SQL with processing via stack or recursive calls

Comment: @astentx You're right. I can only change regex a little bit to handle simple muliple brackets. But for nested brackets, after searching it's hard to find corresponding close bracket using regex.

Answer (score 1):

- Write a parser in Java to parse your expression (or use an existing parser).
- Write a static Java function to convert the abstract syntax tree generated by the parser to your required output and wrap each denominator in the division with a `NULLIF` or `CASE` expression to prevent division-by-zero exceptions being raised.
- Load it into the database using the [`loadjava` utility](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JJDEV/loadjava-tool.htm#JJDEV10060).
- Write a PL/SQL function to wrap the Java function.
- Use the PL/SQL function to transform your dynamic code into something safer.